# Backbone.js: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I experienced this error while adding "`card = new Cards();`" this specific code into my router file. This is the code for my router file.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "build/:deck": "deckbuilder",
        "decks/:id": "deckviewer",
    },

    deckbuilder: function(decks){
        var cards = new Cards();
        this.deckbuild = new Deckbuilder();
        $('#content').html(this.deckbuild.el);
    }

});
```

My collection file is very simple.

```
window.Card = new Backbone.Model.extend({});
window.Cards = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Card,
  url: "/cards"
});
```

I've been trying to find out what's wrong but the error appeared immediately in my backbone.js vendor file. After looking at the trace, the error appeared after calling this line `var cards = new Cards();`. However, I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `new` from `window.Card = new Backbone.Model.extend({});` and from `window.Cards = new Backbone.Collection.extend({});`.

You need use this:

```
window.Card = Backbone.Model.extend({});
window.Cards = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```